Как исправить ошибку 403 при отправке запроса к API OpenAI из России?


const form = document.getElementById("chat-form");
const mytextInput = document.getElementById("mytext");
const responseTextarea = document.getElementById("response");

const API_KEY = "API_KEY";

form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const mytext = mytextInput.value.trim();

   if (mytext) {
      try {
         const response = await fetch(
            "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
            {
               mode: "no-cors",
               method: "POST",
               headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
               },
               body: JSON.stringify({
                  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                  messages: [{ role: "user", content: mytext }],
                  temperature: 1.0,
                  top_p: 0.7,
                  n: 1,
                  stream: false,
                  presence_penalty: 0,
                  frequency_penalty: 0,
               }),
            }
         );

         if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            responseTextarea.value = data.choices[0].message.content;
         } else {
            responseTextarea.value = "Ошибка: Не удалось обработать запрос.";
         }
      } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
         responseTextarea.value = "Ошибка: Не удалось обработать запрос.";
      }
   }
});



При отправке запроса из локального сервера (Open Server) получаю такую ошибку
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions  net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
Как можно это исправить?

использовать впн очевидно

включил впн в браузере, но страница не запускается
